# Workflow of Amaedus Flight Booking?

Tags: amadeus

1. Can any buddy tell me the work flow to book flights from Amadeus
2. Which Api use to get token.
3. Shopping,Book Pnr, get Pnr and so on (Apl List name).

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In Self-Service:

[Flight Offers Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search) **-->** [Flight Offers Price](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-price) **-->** [Flight Create Orders](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-create-orders)

Comment: Thx for the reply. But I need soap api's because Amadeus have soap Api's in production and Test Environment.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `postman` to test soap Api's
booking workflow is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEfcT.jpg)

I hope this helps you